# writing in a line in c

Tags: c, file, stdio

i have a c project and i have serious problem , i want to open file and replace line number nb (nb is an int) with "*****" . this is my code could some one help me please ? it show me the word i want to replace that's mean that the pointer is pointing on the wanted line but nothing happen .help me please

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE * f;
    char ch[1024];
    int i, nb;

    i = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &nb ) ;
    f = fopen( "dict.txt", "r+t" );

    while( i < nb )
     {
        fscanf( f, "%s", ch ) ;
        i++;
     }

    printf( "%s", ch );
    fprintf( f, "%s", "****" );
    fclose( f );
}
```

Comment: Why the weird indentation?! Clean up your presentation...

Comment: sorry could you help me ?

Comment: Press the "edit" button, and use the live preview to make sure your post looks nice before you press "submit".

Comment: For one thing, at a glance, I don't think the file is in write mode. Also; There's a lot wrong with using fprintf here, but I'll let someone else answer that - it's more complex than I have time for right now.

Comment: thank you i will clean it now

Comment: what can use so ? help me please

Comment: @kvanberendonck The mode `r+` means "update", i.e. permit both reading and writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've opened the file for reading and writing. According to the [MSDN man page for `fopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) (I am assuming from the `r+t` mode on the file that you are using Visual Studio):

> When the "**r+**", "**w+**", or "**a+**" access type is specified, both reading and writing are allowed (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are **fsetpos**, **fseek**, and **rewind**.

Some other things to keep in mind:

- When `fscanf` reads a string with `%s`, it reads only one word at a time, not a whole line. It is easier to read whole lines of input with `fgets` than with `fscanf`.
- A file consists of a stream of bytes. If the line you want to replace is 47 characters long, then `fprintf(f, "%s", "****")` will only replace the first four bytes in the line.
- That means that if you want to replace line *#nb*, you will need to read in the line, figure out how long it is, then seek back to the beginning of the line and print out the correct number of asterisks.

Try something like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * f;
    char ch[1024];
    int i,nb ;
    fpos_t beginning_of_line;

    i=0;
    scanf("%d",&nb) ;
    f = fopen("dict.txt", "r+t");
    while (i<nb)
      {
        fgetpos(f, &beginning_of_line);
        fgets(ch, 1024, f);
        i++;
      }

    fseek(f, beginning_of_line, SEEK_SET);  // return to beginning of line
    for (i = 0; ch[i] != '\n'; ++i) {
      fputc('*', f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: thank you , i tried your code with "r+t" and "r+" but it still same no changes

Comment: I am surprised that it even compiled -- I left a bug in my `fgets` statement. I have just updated my answer with a complete working program. If it still does not work for you, I recommend that you use a debugger or add `printf` statements to see what it is doing at each step of the process. For simplicity I have also left out any error checking, but checking for errors after each function call may also uncover problems.

Comment: ohhhhhh thank youuuuuu very mush it work now .reallly thank it helped me sooooo mush thank you